# Textarea Options Are Not Selectable

Tags: javascript, css, html, d3.js

I created a multi-select textarea on the right hand side:

```
http://tinyurl.com/d2dbay5
```

Usually I'm not able to make any selections, unless I click on the background and scroll up and down.  Even then, if I try to select another field, I get the same problem.

Also, when you hover over the text around the graph, the textboxes on the left get populated.  When one of the text boxes has more text than there is room form, I get a vertical scrollbar, which is what I want.  But then if I hover over a text field that has less data and come back, I no longer get the scrollbar.

Comment: What's a "multi-select textarea"? Can you please show some html and JS directly in the question rather than just providing a (non-clickable!) link to a mystery page?

Comment: the `<div>` that contains the svg covers the complete page, therefore you cant select any underlying element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are unable to select any of the content of the textareas is that the `<div>` element which creates the svg is positioned via `position: absolute;` which, when combined with the size of the `<div>` results in it being rendered over the top of the rest of the page.

You can solve this in most modern browsers by adding `z-index` values to the css for the elements in question. You want all of the `<div>` elements containing selectable text to have a higher value for their `z-index` than the svg element.

Specifically, fitting this into your current structure, you can add the following to the inline style of the div containing the svg:

```
z-index: 1;
```

And then add the following to each of the css specifications that impact your other divs (e.g. #legend, #legend_title, #right_section, etc):

```
z-index: 2;
```